# Avoid "Cannot index into null array." on for loop comparison

Tags: arrays, powershell, for-loop

I have a for loop that is occasionally generating an error, "Cannot index into a null array."

This is a piece of code that I am using to process an EDI file.  The code functions as intended because the error is generated on a segment of the file that I am not interested in.
This particular loop responsible for reading ahead to identify elements of interest.  The problem is the it is reading through a jagged array.  The first index represents a line of the EDI file and the second represents the elements of the line.  Index 0 of the elements will always exist by 3 can sometimes be a null index because occasionally there on only 3 elements in a line.  I cannot force the 4rth (3) index because that will change the resulting file, adding an empty element where none should exist.  I cannot seem to find a way to make the comparison, `$FileElements[$i2][3] -eq '20'`, skip the null index and just return false.

```
For ($i2=$i1+1; !($FileElements[$i2][0] -eq 'HL' -and $FileElements[$i2][3] -eq '20'); $i2++){
```

Is there a better method of handling this?  Seems like it should recognize that it is null and return false instead of an error.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your error.  Are you sure that your "Cannot index into a null array" isn't caused by $i2 being greater than the number of lines in the file?

Comment: Your a genius...or at least good at pointing out what was right under my nose.  The error was in the middle of the file so I didn't think about the end of the file.  Adding a new If statement and a break has resolved the issue.

Comment: ...but I can't mark your answer unless you make your comment an answer.

Comment: Done.  And I'm certainly no genius.  Are you using the Powershell ISE?  It has debugging capability and it led me right to the problem.

Comment: Not presently, but I might give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce your error exactly, but I did notice that I got the same error when $i2 exceeded the length of the outer array (i.e., number of lines in the file).